# Help needed with perl crypt function

Tags: string, perl, unique, crypt

I am trying to generate a unique string/id given another relatively large string(consisting of a directory path name), thought of using crypt function. However, it's not working as expected, most probably due to my inability to understand.

here the code & output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

print "Enter a string:"; 
chomp(my $string = <STDIN>); 

my $encrypted_string = crypt($string,'di'); 

print "\n  the encrypted string is:$encrypted_string";
```

output:

```
$ perl crypt_test
 Enter a string:abcdefghi

 the encrypted string is:dipcn0ADeg0Jc
$
$ perl crypt_test
 Enter a string:abcdefgh

 the encrypted string is:dipcn0ADeg0Jc
$
$
$ perl crypt_test
 Enter a string:abcde

 the encrypted string is:diGyhSp4Yvj4M
$
```

I couldn't understand why it returned the same encrypted string for the first two strings and differed for the third one. Note that salt is same for all.

Comment: If you want to make unique strings, try Data::UUID. As you can see from Mat's answer, the `crypt()` function is ancient and limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crypt(3)` function only takes into account the first eight chars of the input string:

> By taking the lowest 7 bits of each of the first eight characters  of  the  key,  a  56-bit  key  is  obtained.   This  56-bit  key is used to encrypt repeatedly a constant string (usually a string con‐
>          sisting of all zeros).  The returned value points to the encrypted password, a series of  13  print‐
>          able ASCII characters (the first two characters represent the salt itself).

So what you are seeing is by design - from `perlfunc`:

```
crypt PLAINTEXT,SALT
       Creates a digest string exactly like the crypt(3) function in the C library
```